R Plumber: Redirect at end of endpoint function execution?
I'd like to have a user click a link that updates the status of a user, which has a plumber endpoint to do the updating.  Then at the end of the function that does the updating, I'd like to redirect the user to a 'display' page that displays the result of the update.  I think it should look something like the following.  I cannot seem to find how to make plumber forward a user's browser page.
#* Update Status
#* @get /update
#* @serializer html
function(id, status_to){
    # ... Update status for 'id'

    # ... How to then redirect user to '/display?id=1', etc.?
}

#* Display Status
#* @get /display
#* @serializer html
function(id){
    # .. display status for '/display?id=1', etc.?
}

